# How to lock texture tile size while painting?

Tags: texturing, camera, texture-painting, units

I am a new to the blender.
While I was painting texture to the mesh surface, I noticed that if I move camera(view) even a little bit and paint again, the new painted area texture tiles are different sizes than other previous painted texture tiles. If I zoom the camera and paint, texture tiles are smaller in the mesh surface, If I zoom out texture tiles are bigger.

How could I lock the texture tile size so that if I zoom in or zoom out, it doesn't affect to tile size?

Comment: This is really important to me as well. It just seems impossible to use any textures otherwise.

Comment: To my knowledge this isn't possible

Comment: Even basic texture software have this feature, how it's possible that blender doesn't have it. Someone who has better blender knowledge, please confirm this. If it is true, I will start to program it myself for the blender.

Comment: Or just use Zbrush for better quality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a partial answer. If you want to keep the tile size same while texture painting, you should paint textures only inside of the UV editor.

1. Unwrap your mesh.
2. Change your view to the "UV/Image editor".
3. Select "View" and change it to the "Paint".
4. Then go back to the "3D View" and select the "Texture Paint".
5. Go back to the "UV/Image editor" and now you could paint textures directly to the texture atlas.

**You could control the tile size by adjusting the Brush Radius.**

[image]
[image]