# How do i make the texture paint brush stay the same size?

Tags: texture-painting

So, in texture paint, when I am texturing, I use a brush size. But when I zoom out, the brush gets bigger and makes me shrink it. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock texture tile size while painting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18862/how-to-lock-texture-tile-size-while-painting)

Comment: Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/how-to-make-brush-size-lock-in-texture-paint

Comment: @LukeD that second link has no answers or comments... and it says it's not working other than in sculpt...? the first is about a workaround, but changes how you paint. I think this is a missing feature in blender texture paint, it could work like in sculpt, perhaps, and it should be requested, maybe (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests)

Comment: @m.ardito I know what's there, although it's still duplicate. Yes, this is missing feature, sadly.